# Zend 2 Error : Uncaught exception 'Zend\Stdlib\Exception\InvalidArgumentException'

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I retrieve data from Zend 2 session container on layout via bootstarp method.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    $user = $this->getUser($sm);
    $viewModel = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
    $viewModel->user = ($user) ? $user: false;
}

public function getUser($sm)
{
    $user= false;
    $userTable= $sm->get('User\Model\UserTable');
    $userSession = new Container('userSession');

    //RETRIEVE USER FROM DB

    return $user;
}
```

Now i'm getting following error sometimes (not always)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Stdlib\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array instead' in /var/www/T2oRecruitment/app/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject.php:184 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/T2oRecruitment/app/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject.php(411): Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject->exchangeArray(NULL) #1 [internal function]: Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject->unserialize('a:4:{s:7:"stora...') #2 
/var/www/T2oRecruitment/app/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Session/SessionManager.php(95): session_start() #3 
/var/www/T2oRecruitment/app/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Session/AbstractContainer.php(78): Zend\Session\SessionManager->start() #4 
/var/www/T2oRecruitment/app/module/Application/Module.php(22): Zend\Session\AbstractContainer->__construct('userSession') #5 
/var/www/T2oRecruitment/app/module/Application/Module.php(43): Application\Module->getUser(Object(Zend\S in /var/www/T2oRecruitment/app/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject.php on line 184
```

What is the issue ?

Comment: I think, session start is not happening for sometime and that's why its showing the issue.

Comment: 2nd row of the stack trace: Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject->exchangeArray(NULL).
Are you setting something on the container $userSession? It seems it has issues converting the Container

Comment: In getUser($sm) method i retrieve user's id from session and query db. don't set anything to session.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this:

In Module.php file --->

```
use Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig, Zend\Session\SessionManager,
    Zend\Session\Container, Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
// other libraries

public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    $config = $sm->get('Config');

    $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
    $sessionConfig->setOptions($config['session']);
    $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
    $sessionManager->start();

    $user = $this->userSession($sm);
    $viewModel = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
    $viewModel->user = ($user) ? $user: false;
}
```

In module.config.php file --->

```
return array(
    'session' => array(
        'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
        'use_cookies' => true,
        'cookie_httponly' => true
    ),
);
```

Hope, this will give some idea to you, for fixing your issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it necessary to use session manager and start sessions ? i have used session container without the manager.

Answer (score 0):

There is official bug https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4821 
it's still open, but you can check the progress...